# Animating a subview with CentreY constraint

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have a UITableViewCell with two UILabels and a UISwitch. The labels are multilined and placed on top of each other. The UISwitch is centred vertically. When I turn off the switch I hide one of the labels and the height of the row changes. This causes the switch to jump though I call:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Here is my tableviewcell class implementation:

```
 - (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
  [super setBounds:bounds];

  self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
}

- (void)setUpView{

    self.numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Quote number %ld",    [self.cellData[@"rowNumber"] integerValue]];
    [self.controlSwitch setOn:[self.cellData[@"checked"] boolValue]];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    if ([self.controlSwitch isOn]) {
        self.quoteLabel.text = self.cellData[@"quote"];
        self.quoteLabel.hidden = NO;
        self.bottomConst.constant = 10;
    }else{
        self.quoteLabel.text = @"";
        self.quoteLabel.hidden = YES;
        self.bottomConst.constant = 0;
    }
 }];


}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  [self.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
  [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

  self.numberLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.numberLabel.frame);
  self.quoteLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.quoteLabel.frame);
}


- (IBAction)removeQuote:(id)sender {
   [self.delegate updateCell:self];
}
```

The constraint settings on the UITableViewCell looks like this.

[image]

When the switch is turned on, I'm simply unhide the Quote label and set the text. 
[Here](https://youtu.be/OrJt26s_NOc) is the link on how it looks like. Is this the default behavior or is there a way I can control the movement of the switch when the row animates?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
[self.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView commitAnimations];
...
```

Comment: That didn't work. Its the constraint centreY on the switch that causes it to jump